# Проброс gpg-agent

Tags: ssh, systemd, gpg, altlinux

Система на `systemd`.
Выполняю `ssh-add` в начале каждого сеанса работы.

Добавил для одной из `Host`-записей в `~/.ssh/config` проброс `ssh-agent`:

```
Host server
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
        ForwardAgent yes
        RemoteForward /run/user/500/gnupg/S.gpg-agent /run/user/500/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
```

Затем выполнил следующие команды:

```
$ systemctl --user enable --now gpg-agent.socket
$ systemctl --user enable --now gpg-agent-extra.socket
```

Оба сокета "запускаются" успешно:

```
● gpg-agent.socket - GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/gpg-agent.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-02-25 16:33:35 MSK; 27min ago
   Triggers: ● gpg-agent.service
       Docs: man:gpg-agent(1)
     Listen: /run/user/500/gnupg/S.gpg-agent (Stream)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-500.slice/user@500.service/app.slice/gpg-agent.socket

фев 25 16:33:35 komputer systemd[3591]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.

● gpg-agent-extra.socket - GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted)
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/gpg-agent-extra.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-02-25 16:33:35 MSK; 27min ago
   Triggers: ● gpg-agent.service
       Docs: man:gpg-agent(1)
     Listen: /run/user/500/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra (Stream)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-500.slice/user@500.service/app.slice/gpg-agent-extra.socket

фев 25 16:33:35 komputer systemd[3591]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
```

На удалённой системе выполняю (на всякий случай):

```
$ rm -rf /run/user/500/gnupg
```

После этого подключаюсь к серверу и смотрю ключи

```
$ ssh server
[server ~] $ gpg2 -K
/home/serg/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
-------------------------------
sec#  ed25519 2022-01-25 [SC]
      911BCF398150BA2F25DD8994B240A6DA71FB5DC9
uid         [ неизвестно ] Sergey Valenkov <sergval@mail.su>
ssb#  cv25519 2022-01-25 [E]
```

Казалось бы, что всё хорошо.

Однако, если я параллельно открою ещё один эмулятор терминала, подключусь к серверу, то из обоих ssh-сессий я могу получать информацию о ключах. А вот когда я прерываю последнюю открытую сессию, то в первой открытой ssh-сессии я не могу получить доступ к ключами.

После того как отключить от сервера все открытые ssh-сессии, и попробовать подключиться заново, то доступа к ключам вообще нет (даже не выводятся).

И только после удаления на сервере директории с сокетами (`/run/user/500/gnupg`) с последующим открытием дополнительной ssh-сессии, можно опять получать доступ к ключами.

Мне кажется, что я что-то делаю не так, но не могу понять что.
Прошу помочь разобраться.

*(почта в ключе, имена хостов, даты и время изменены для сохранения конфиденциальности)*

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо расшарить SSH-сессию в вашем SSH-соединении. Для этого добавьте настройки нужного хоста в `~/.ssh/config` следующее:

```
     ControlMaster = auto
     ControlPath = ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
```

В вашем случае получится примерно следующее:

```
Host server
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
        ControlMaster = auto
        ControlPath = ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
        ForwardAgent yes
        RemoteForward /run/user/500/gnupg/S.gpg-agent /run/user/500/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
```

Подробнее об этом можно почитать в `ssh_config(5)`.

Также на стороне сервера необходимо в `/etc/openssh/sshd_config` указать следующее:

```
StreamLocalBindUnlink yes
```

Это необходимо для того, чтобы удалить "протухшие" прокинутые сокеты из предыдущих, уже закрытых, SSH-сессий.

Если доступа к редактированию настроек `sshd` нету, тогда нужно будет удалять сокеты скриптом (или вручную). Для этого, к примеру, можно (на удалённой машине) в `~/.bash_logout` написать следующее:

```
USER_SESSIONS_COUNT=$(users | sed 's/\ /\n/g' | grep $USER | wc -l)

if [ $USER_SESSIONS_COUNT -eq 1 ];
then
        rm -rf /run/user/$UID/gnupg/*
fi
```